# Требуется ли запятая? (При этом + уточнение)

Tags: пунктуация

Следующее предложение: "При этом (?) согласно годовому отчету, крупнейшим держателем акция является Газпром".

Нужна ли после "при этом" запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "При этом, согласно годовому отчету, крупнейшим держателем акция является Газпром". 
Это обособленный обстоятельственный оборот с производным предлогом "СОГЛАСНО", который находится в середине предложения, после присоединительного союза ПРИ ЭТОМ.

Похожий пример: "При этом, согласно закону о приватизации, правительство имеет право формировать дополнительные списки".

В то же время в ряде случаев, в том числе при незначительной распространенности оборота, он может не обособляться, например: "При этом согласно условиям заключенных с физлицами договоров организация возмещает им расходы по проезду, проживанию и на мобильную связь".

Answer (score 1):

Указанная запятая нужна. Обстоятельственные обороты «согласно + существительное  могут выделяться знаками препинания (запятыми).Напр.: <<Я несколько отодвинулся от стены и, согласно рыцарским правилам нашего базара, тоже положил руки в карманы. >>В. Короленко, В дурном обществе.
Оборот с предлогом «согласно не выделяется запятыми, если он является частью сказуемого или тесно связан со сказуемым по смыслу.

<<В комнате Коли вечер наступал согласно законам природы, поскольку свет там давно не горел>>. Л. Петрушевская, Козёл Ваня. Подробнее здесь: http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=376.O_sP7yt3qpnetq-EmsZP7Rx9ae8eLuqnbcmpDEYYG3eaw_g2tlZTZMG3YUe6EPn4H-wWTN0Zj6bw6ZaLWC5UjhNEAqlkpJOtSlRyVp-53HQNPQOGs9F_A61QTYHEXtNskyxmDWxOsj5JyyZD9WVt2k5eL1AQox_ldCXF3mwgX3COawv5YsQYV8ijDb9hRfq75Vvkp4Ezp7s98X3x-4Dmxvmbw4ofhwZGHP2q8agL9AGcB3_8atwKEWTc3qNEfj7Q.9759d804334c45c36bbf11181eed3436f394fa3d&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xuhyw5P1wAdC5ECtwX3djqA12G51o5Dhdv9vF7P5vxyce_EdWVvnD6xeYl-fcSneLqwYfaBCIRXLwxX6Lir2CKoJbXNhvJ7ZG5KPADPUUsTWYH809q319qE2KxHH5Yd7CBe7qi2t_xCrLvlodj4T_nchCrKjv-hJZhoAL7uV4Xx5mbZ25cRfrPmUX-MxS1d414&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbzRZRkExTE1SekJnZXNpMFJkZnhnbnJaYk9RdnlHTmVNckFaMHQ1YWpOZXFoWE9wbFZCSWZQSElJSTNXNGdZaXJobm5lZmFqTDFxX0NHWU80bWlkRHZVWF9ySXlLTTBwOUhRR0cwSWV1eTU&b64e=2&sign=4ce93af3d07e78f720aabda57edd1468&keyno=0&l10n=ru